# how to process large amounts of .jnb files?

Tags: python, sigmaplot

I am working on backing up 5,000+ files of sigma plot data. Right now, I have to do it all manually by exporting to .csv and .txt files, and the tabs of data all have to be individually exported. Has anybody had any luck finding a way to process these files? I'd really like to use python to write the back up files, but I'll take any help you have.